# Regex: replace img tag with its alt attribute

Tags: regex, text, tags

I have a string in variable frontendtext which contains text and img tags. I want the img tags in it to get replaced by the alt attribute value using only regex.

```
var frontend1 = frontendtext.replace(/<img.*?alt="(.*?)".*>/g, 'O');
```

It replaces my string with `O`, but i want to replace only the img tag with the alt and the rest of the string remains the same.

Comment: Can u tell me how to? coz i'm not a regex guy. I am like Jon Snow of regex, I know nothin

Comment: show the current `frontendtext` contents

Comment: hello<img src="img/blank.gif" class="img" style="display:inline-block;width:25px;height:25px; background:url('img/emojisprite_0.png') -150px 0px no-repeat; background-size:675px 175px;" alt="" title=":heart_eyes:">Roberts. How are you<img src="img/blank.gif" class="img" style="display:inline-block;width:25px;height:25px; background:url('img/emojisprite_4.png') -25px -100px no-repeat; background-size:850px 175px;" alt="❓" title=":question:">

Comment: After replacing the tags it would look like this: helloRoberts. How are you❓

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using the capture group, you can replace the entire string with the capture group reference

```js
var frontendtext = "Hello this is an image <img src=\"image.jpg\" alt=\"!!Just some image alt text!!\" /> and foo bar.";
var frontend1 = frontendtext.replace(/<img.*?alt="(.*?)"[^\>]+>/g, '$1');
alert(frontend1);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yoqkdapa/

The regular expression is;

`<img` - match the `<img` tag

`.*?alt=` - match everything up to the `alt` attribute

`"(.*?)"` - match everything between the quotes after the alt tag

`[^\>]+` - match everything lazily else except the closing `>` of the `<img` tag

`>` - match the close of the `<img` tag

Comment: If you write to the DOM, the browser renders it as a space: https://jsfiddle.net/yoqkdapa/3/

Comment: can u please explain the expression a bit for others who will read this on later stages.

Comment: I changed the + to a * for var frontend1 = frontendtext.replace(/<img.*?alt="(.*?)"[^\>]+>/g, '$1'); and that worked for me